# Is there a way to loop through a pandas dataframe by row and print each row as a line with the corresponding team id and results to a text file?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, text-files

I have one csv imported in a dataframe containing the result of EPL matches and a text file that holds each team name with a team id number.

```
df_results:
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HomeGoals   AwayGoals
0   Man United  Leicester      2            1
1   Bournemouth Cardiff        2            0
2   Fulham  Crystal Palace     0            2
3   Huddersfield    Chelsea    0            3
4   Newcastle   Tottenham      1            2
```

```
teams.txt:
1, Man United
2, Bournemouth
3, Fulham
4, Huddersfield
5, Newcastle
6, Watford
7, Wolves
8, Arsenal
9, Liverpool
10, Southampton
11, Cardiff
12, Chelsea
13, Everton
14, Leicester
15, Tottenham
16, West Ham
17, Brighton
18, Burnley
19, Man City
20, Crystal Palace
```

Is there a way to loop through a pandas dataframe by row and print each row as a line with the corresponding team id and results to a text file, separated by commas?

For example:

```
0   Man United  Leicester   2          1
```

End result:

```
1, 1, 2, 14, -1, 1
```

```
First column = home team id
Second column = 1
Third column = HomeGoals
Fourth column = Away Team id
Fifth column = -1
Sixth column = AwayGoals
```

The text file will end up looking something like this:

```
1, 1, 2, 14, -1, 1
2, 1, 2, 11, -1, 0
3, 1, 0, 20, -1, 2
4, 1, 0, 12, -1, 3
5, 1, 1, 15, -1, 2
```

Has anyone done this before? I tried to figure this out on my own but, it just led me to transcribing this manually. Please let me know if more clarity is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a crosswalk `xwalk` between `team_id` and `team_name` where `team_name` has a one-to-one perfect match with `HomeTeam` etc:

```
df['home_team_id'] = df['HomeTeam'].map(xwalk.set_index('team_name')['team_id'])
df['away_team_id'] = df['AwayTeam'].map(xwalk.set_index('team_name')['team_id'])
```

Then reorder your columns in your desired order and print as CSV passing `header=False`. You may need to create columns `-1` and `1` by assigning with `df['column_name'] = -1` etc.

Comment: The names don't match